# subscription value is neither array nor pointer

Tags: c, arrays

First of all i would just like to say sorry if i seem like an idiot in this post, i am completely new to C. Anyway, my problem is that i get this weird error while following a YT tutorial and i am trying to make a program to calculate best player in Hockey by having arrays of player ids how many goals they have scored and how many goals they have played and for each player divide goals by games played. At last i print out the best score and player id, but for some reason i get an error, here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    int players[5] = {5, 3, 4, 2, 1};
    int goals = {3, 2, 5, 4, 5};
    int gamesPlayed = {1, 1, 3, 2, 2};
    float ppg[5];
    float bestPPG = 0.0;
    int bestPlayer;

    for (i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        ppg[i] = (float)goals[i] / (float)gamesPlayed[i];
        if (ppg[i] > bestPPG)
        {
            bestPlayer = players[i];
            bestPPG = ppg[i];
        }
    }

    printf("The best player was %d", bestPlayer);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
line: 16
error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output (assumed to be compiler output, not runtime) tells you the error. The problem was that you declared an integer, but tried to use it as an array. The error says "subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector". **Subscripted** here means you access a variable with the **[] operator**, which can in C only be done on arrays, pointers, (or vectors and classes overloading [] in C++). Therefore

```
int goals = {3, 2, 5, 4, 5};
```

has to be

```
int goals[] = {3, 2, 5, 4, 5};
```

and

```
int gamesPlayed = {1, 1, 3, 2, 2};
```

has to be

```
int gamesPlayed[] = {1, 1, 3, 2, 2};
```

After that correction, I get the result:

> The best player was 5

Comment: Those lines in OP's code are errors - if no error is seen then OP needs to change compiler settings.

Comment: I understood that the output the OP mentioned actually were the compuler errors. I updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: I know `int goals = {3, 2, 5, 4, 5};` is wrong and doesn't make sense, but is it undefined behavior? If it isn't, is `goals` guaranteed to be `3`?

Comment: @CoolGuy it is a constraint violation due to there being more initializers than elements (5 > 1)

Comment: @CoolGuy IMO yes, although a couple of people hold the view that constraint violations are not necessarily undefined

Comment: @M.M: A constraint violation requires a diagnostic to be issued; undefined behavior does not.  So in that respect, they are not the same.

Comment: @JohnBode I never claimed they were the same, the question was whether this code with a constraint violation is also undefined behaviour